# how to add a character to a duplicated string and then remove it

Tags: r

I have a data with one column of string and 10 columns of values. I cannot set the first column as row columns and I figured out that I have duplicated strings in my first column. so what I did was to identify them like below

```
dftt <- data.frame(myname[which(duplicated(myname)),])
```

A small portion of dftt is shown below

```
dftt<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 1L), .Label = c("alp-1", 
"cfim-2", "eps-8", "fln-2", "istr-1", "lev-11", "pqn-87", "ret-1", 
"sao-1", "sup-26", "vab-10"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

What I want is to add something to duplicate strings to make them unique so that I can be able to set it as row names but keep and index of it or something than after I manipulate the data, I get rid of them

As an example it could be number or specific letter

```
#       V1
#1  lev-11
#2  lev-11_nik1
#3   fln-2
#4  lev-11_nik2
#5  cfim-2
#6   sao-1
#7  sup-26
#8   alp-1
#9  pqn-87
#10 vab-10
#11 sup-26_nik1
#12  eps-8
#13  ret-1
#14 istr-1
#15 sup-26_nik2
#16 sup-26_nik3
#17  alp-1_nik1
#18 sup-26_nik4
#19 vab-10
#20  alp-1_nik2
```

I know probably I must use *paste0* or *paste* but I don't know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, determine the duplicates:

```
dup <- duplicated(dftt$V1)
```

Now make all values in the column unique with `make.unique()`:

```
dftt$V1 <- make.unique(as.character(dftt$V1), sep = "_nik")
head(dftt)
#             V1
# 1       lev-11
# 2  lev-11_nik1
# 3        fln-2
# 4  lev-11_nik2
# 5       cfim-2
# 6        sao-1
```

To return the values back to their original state, remove `_nik` and trailing digit(s) from the end of the string with `sub()`:

```
dftt$V1[dup] <- sub("_nik\\d+$", "", dftt$V1[dup])
head(dftt)
#        V1
# 1  lev-11
# 2  lev-11
# 3   fln-2
# 4  lev-11
# 5  cfim-2
# 6   sao-1
```

Note that this will change the column type from factor to character.